# slightly complex matching condition

Tags: c#, linq, logical-operators

The code below represents what I am trying to write. The requirement is that the tax profile should match the correct currency. I have written the if conditions in my code below. However there are more than 100 tax profiles that are read via a database. **Should I write if conditions for all 100 of them or is there a better way to code?**

```
using System;

namespace MatchCondition
{
    class MatchCondition
    {
        private const int TaxAmerica1 = 100;
        private const int TaxAmerica2 = 200;
        private const int TaxIndia1 = 300;
        private const int TaxIndia2 = 400;

        private const int Rupee =100;
        private const int Dollar =200;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {

                int currencyId = int.Parse(args[0]);
                int taxProfileId = int.Parse(args[1]);
                if (currencyId == Rupee && (taxProfileId == TaxIndia1 || taxProfileId == TaxIndia2))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("All is well!");
                }
                else if(currencyId == Dollar && (taxProfileId == TaxAmerica1 || taxProfileId == TaxAmerica2))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("All is well!");
                }
                else if (taxProfileId == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("All is well!");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Mismatch Detected!");
                }

            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put all your valid combinations in a hashtable, i.e. `IDictionary` and go from there.

For example:

```
var validCombinations = new Dictionary<int, List<int>>();
validCombinations.Add(Rupee, new List<int> { TaxIndia1, TaxIndia2 });
validCombinations.Add(Dollar, new List<int> { TaxAmerica1, TaxAmerica2 });

int currencyId = int.Parse(args[0]);
int taxProfileId = int.Parse(args[1]);

List<int> validTaxes;

if (taxProfileId == 0 ||
    (validCombinations.TryGetValue(currencyId, out validTaxes) &&
     validTaxes.Contains(taxProfileId)))
{
    Console.WriteLine("All is well!");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Mismatch Detected!");
}
```

You could also populate the dictionary with combinations read from a database table, so you don't have to hardcode them. YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mapping dictionary of lists as an alternative

You could restructure your code like this:

So you just need to add to the validCurrencies Dictionary for each set of valid currency/tax profiles.  Note that this is just to give you an alternative to writing 100 conditions, you will need to test and make the code robust yourself.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MatchCondition
{
    class MatchCondition
    {
        private enum TaxProfileEnum
        {
            Default = 0,
            America1 = 100,
            America2 = 200,
            India1 = 300,
            India2 = 400,
        }

        private enum CurrencyEnum
        {
            Rupee = 100,
            Dollar = 200,
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Dictionary<CurrencyEnum, List<TaxProfileEnum>> validCurrencies = new Dictionary<CurrencyEnum, List<TaxProfileEnum>>()
                {
                    { CurrencyEnum.Rupee, new List<TaxProfileEnum>()  { TaxProfileEnum.India1, TaxProfileEnum.India2 } },
                    { CurrencyEnum.Dollar, new List<TaxProfileEnum>() { TaxProfileEnum.America1, TaxProfileEnum.America2 } },
                };

                CurrencyEnum currency = (CurrencyEnum)int.Parse(args[0]);
                TaxProfileEnum taxProfile = (TaxProfileEnum)int.Parse(args[1]);

                if (taxProfile == TaxProfileEnum.Default)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("All is well!");
                    return;
                }

                List<TaxProfileEnum> validTaxes;
                if (validCurrencies.TryGetValue(currency, out validTaxes) && validTaxes.Contains(taxProfile))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("All is well!");
                    return;
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Mismatch Detected!");
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dang, Stackoverflow went down as I submitted my answer... had to wait before submitting.